# Understanding AnswersWithDelay Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

Have come across use of `AnswerWithDelay` in mockito to introduce delay in method calls. For example:

```
doAnswer(new AnswersWithDelay(100, new CallsRealMethods())).when(spyObject).methodName(someValue);
```

Have few doubts how this work?

- Lets say a thread is calling above line. My understanding it just delays the call to `methodName` and waiting is done before actually calling the method.
- If above is true is there a way to call method and then wait for delay and then call rest of the method code?

Answer (score 1):

Please check [AnswersWithDelay](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/3.x/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/stubbing/answers/AnswersWithDelay.java) source code:

```
@Override
public Object answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(sleepyTime);
    return answer.answer(invocation);
}
```

- It sleeps for the given amount of time
- Than it returns the answer

As the class is not final, it is trivial to subclass it and reverse that order.